# Redirecting apache-flume logger output of specific source (or type) to a different log file

Tags: apache, logging, log4j, flume

Is it possible to redirect apache-flume's logger output of specific source (or type) to a different log file, so that it is easy for interpreting?

For example, http-source output to http.log, exec-source output to exec.log

Is the above achievable in flume?

Comment: If I've understood well, you want the log traces for each component (source, channel or sink) to be written to an independent file, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right @frb